# Why can't I use a lambda instead of a method reference in Collectors.groupingBy?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8 Stream.collect function, when I use `Collectors.groupingBy()`, I notice the parameter could be

```
Function<? super T,​? extends K> classifier
```

Here I have to use a `::` method reference. Why I can't use a lambda instead?

```
public  class TransAction{
     public TransAction(String s,Integer v) {
        str=s;
        value=v;
     }
     private String str;
     private Integer value; 
     //getter/setters...
}
//in main()
TransAction[] a = { new TransAction("small", 41), ..., new TransAction("big", 122) };
Map<String, List<TransAction>> c = Arrays.stream(a).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TransAction::getStr));
//Arrays.stream(a).collect(Collectors.groupingBy((a)->a.getStr()));
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can, just don't use twice the same name `a`

```
Map<String, List<TransAction>> c = Arrays.stream(a)
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getStr()));
```

Comment: Thanx, it is naming problem.

Comment: @Bill how do you code ? With an IDE or just a file, and javac/java in a terminal ? Because this is the kind of error that is clearly given

Comment: @Bill You may think about accepting the answer so ;)